# How to fix msgcat::mc error after running app from PyInstaller on MacOS Mojave?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

I am trying to create bundle app of my project for MacOS using PyInstaller 3.4 with Python 3.6.8 (not brew, installed from python.org). For the first time running of application yielded the error:

```
[2195] Failed to execute script pyi_rth__tkinter
```

I have found a solution to this problem on https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3753#issuecomment-432464838. After that running of AppName.app/Contents/MacOS/AppName goes without any error. But if I try to run AppName.app, it gives:

```
  File "tkinter/__init__.py", line 2023, in __init__
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "msgcat::mc"
```

To ensure that the project code or manually created `spec`-file for PyInstaller are not a problem, I wrote a simple script:

```py
import sys
import logging
from pathlib import Path
import tkinter as tk

logging.basicConfig(
    filename=Path('~/Desktop/pyapp.log').expanduser()
)
logger = logging.getLogger()

try:
    tk._test()
except Exception as e:
    logger.exception(e)
finally:
    sys.exit()
```

Created bundle with `pyinstaller main.py --windowed` and it behaves the same. Content of `pyapp.log` after running `dist/main.app`:

```
ERROR:root:invalid command name "msgcat::mc"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "tkinter/__init__.py", line 3988, in _test
  File "tkinter/__init__.py", line 2023, in __init__
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "msgcat::mc"
```

Comment: I ran the code and it works perfectly fine when I run dist/main/main.exe. But for some reason .app doesn't even open on my Mac after updating to Mojave. I think PyInstaller doesn't support tkinter GUI on Mojave yet. I could be wrong as Kivy GUI .app does work perfectly fine with `--noconsole` flag.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, Kivy is not an option for the project.

Comment: This is https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3820 It is a bug in the tk/console.tcl file. https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3820#issuecomment-663697670
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3820#issuecomment-702448239

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyInstaller does not copy properly tkinter and tcl data on macos. I wrote a script for doing it manually:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
app_root="dist/APPNAME.app/Contents/MacOS"
python_path="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib"

cp -r "$python_path/tcl8" "$app_root/tcl8"
cp -r "$python_path/tcl8.6" "$app_root/tcl"
cp -r "$python_path/tk8.6" "$app_root/tk"
```